# Flutter - > UploadTask method OnComplete does not exists

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I see a lot of exercises that put onComplete but with my code this is the error

The getter 'onComplete' isn't defined for the type 'UploadTask'.
Try importing the library that defines 'onComplete', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'onComplete'

WHY ??

```
void uploadImage() async {
    if (safeNeuralNetwork()) {
      //Subir imagen a firebase storage
      final Reference postImageRef =
          FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("Post Images");
      var timeKey = DateTime.now();
    
      print(sampleImage);
      UploadTask uploadTask =
          postImageRef.child(timeKey.toString() + ".jpg").putFile(sampleImage);
      var imageUrl =
          await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
      url = imageUrl.toString();
      print(url);
      // Guardar el post en la bbdd
      saveToDatabase(url);
      //Regresar en Home
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 28):

I think you don't need `onComplete` anymore, and can just `await` the `Future` that's returned from `putFile`.

For the latest code samples, always check the [FlutterFire documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/overview), for example: [uploading a file](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage#file-uploads).

Answer (score 16):

Thank you very much it works. This is the final code

```
  print(sampleImage);
  UploadTask uploadTask =
      postImageRef.child(timeKey.toString() + ".jpg").putFile(sampleImage);
  print('aaa');
  print(uploadTask);
  var imageUrl = await (await uploadTask).ref.getDownloadURL();
  url = imageUrl.toString();
  print(url);
  // Guardar el post en la bbdd
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the TaskSnapshot class instead. You don't need onComplete.

Example:

```
TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask;
```